# Bizarre interaction with floats and Viewport Percentage units

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using a javascript loop I'm trying to cover the body with divs that are sized using viewport percentage widths and heights and have float:left.

That means 100 of these divs should cover the entire viewport. However it doesn't work that way, instead it moves the 10th down a line.

Javascript

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.className= 'square';
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

CSS

```
.square {
width: 10vw;
height: 10vh;
background-color: aqua;
float: left;
}
.square:hover {
background-color:red;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/msqjd27y/)

I have set the margin to 0 on the body. The issue arises when I make 100 of these divs.

Comment: html, body { margin: 0; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of margins on the body. The elements are sized relative to the entire viewport, but the body width is less than this because of the default margin on body.

https://jsfiddle.net/msqjd27y/1/

Just add
`body { margin: 0; }`

If you want to keep the margins on body, and still want 10 elements, you don't want to use the viewport units. You would use `width: 10%` like this https://jsfiddle.net/msqjd27y/2/

Comment: When you set it to make 100 of them it still has a gap on the right.

Comment: Travis, I am not getting a gap when there's 100: https://jsfiddle.net/msqjd27y/3/

Comment: I want it to cover the entire viewport. So I left the width as 10vw. When it's set to 10vw there is a gap. https://jsfiddle.net/msqjd27y/4/

Comment: I am still not seeing a gap there, what browser are you using? I see it taking up the entire viewport.

Comment: I'm using chrome. The gap only seems to appear when I resize the area but then it remains.

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior on my chrome 48 OSX. I see a fully covered page of cyan, and hovering over the elements on the corners gives a red square with no gap. Resizing works for me too.

Comment: Well I managed to get it to work by setting overflow to hidden on my browser test. Something about the scrollbar seems to be affecting it. Thank you for your help man.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the body element, you must write a css rule like this:
body{ margin:0 } to solve your problem